# select first column in a 3d ndarray

Tags: python, select, numpy, multidimensional-array

I got a simple question for python.
Instead of iterating over the first line for a 3D `ndarray`, I want to select the whole column.
So lets say:instead of:

```
print test[0][20][33]
print test[1][20][33]
...
```

I want to put something like:

```
 print test[:][20][33]
```

But this does not work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all the terms inside the square brackets:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = np.array(np.arange(24)).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> v
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> v[:, 1, 3]
array([ 7, 19])
```

.. although I'm not sure I'd call that the first column.  You can easily shuffle the indices to get whatever you're after, though:

```
>>> v[0, :, 0]
array([0, 4, 8])
>>> v[1, 1, :]
array([16, 17, 18, 19])
```

[[relevant doc section on indexing]](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)

Comment: clear and straight, thanks a lot!
just started browsing some of your other answers and good to read & learn :)
Best... R